# question about correlation of variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

Here is an interview question I had and  cannot figure out how to solve it. Any hint?

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be 3 random variables such that $\mathsf{Corr}(X, Y)=0.9$ and $\mathsf{Corr}(Y, Z)=0.8$. What is the minimum correlation between $X$ and $Z$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Think of correlation as a cosine of the angle between random variables. Then from formula for $\cos(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$, the answer becomes $0.9\cdot 0.8-\sqrt{1-0.9^2}\sqrt{1-0.8^2}$

Comment: I have: cos(a+b) = cos(a)cos(b) - sin(a)sin(b) . I also take into account that corr(X,Y) = -cos(X,Y). then after replacing I have an exact equality if I am not wrong? ( replacing sin by square root of 1 - cos square)

Comment: Well, these are NOT 2-D angles, so the formula is not exact, but only a minimum if $X,Y,Z$ "lie in the same plane" with $Y$ inbetween the other two.

Comment: got your point. So how can we figure out it is a min and not a max for instance?

Comment: Imagine $X,Y,Z$ in 3-D. Then the maximum angle (corresponding to minimal correlation) between $X,Z$ is $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ and the minimum is $|\alpha_1-\alpha_2|$.

Comment: Here is a related question with answers:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131065/non-transitivity-of-correlation-correlations-between-gender-and-brain-size-and/131069#131069

Answer (score 0):

This Answer deals with the special case of normal distributions. Without loss of generality in this case, we use distributions with zero means
and unit standard deviations. Our purpose is to construct three such
normal random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ with $Cor(X_1, X_2) = \rho_{12}$
and $Cor(X_2, X_3) = \rho_{23}$. Then we show that 
$Cor(X_1, X_3) = \rho_{13} = \rho_{12}\rho_{23}$.

We use $X_1 \sim Norm(0,1)$ along with auxilliarly $S_1 \sim Norm(0,1)$ to
make $X_2 \sim Norm(0,1)$ such that $Cor(X_1, X_2) = \rho_{12}$, for a given
$\rho_{12}.$ Let 
$$X_2 = \rho_{12}X_1 + \delta_{12}S_1,$$ 
where $\delta_{12} = \sqrt{1 - \rho_{12}^2}.$
It is elementary to show that $V(X_2) = 1$ and, by the independence of $X_1$ and $S_1$,
that $Cov(X_1,X_2) = Cor(X_1,X_2) = \rho_{12}.$

We use $X_2 \sim Norm(0,1)$ along with auxillarly $S_2 \sim Norm(0,1)$ to
make $X_3 \sim Norm(0,1)$ such that $Cor(X_2, X_3) = \rho_{23}$, for a given
$\rho_{23}.$ Let 
$$X_3 = \rho_{23}X_2 + \delta_{23}S_2,$$ 
where $\delta_{23} = \sqrt{1 - \rho_{23}^2}.$
It is also elementary to show that $V(X_3) = 1$ and (as claimed) that 
$Cor(X_2,X_3) = \rho_{12}\rho_{23}.$

The following simulation in R illustrates these relationships for
vectors of length one million for $\rho_{12} = 0.8$ and 
$\rho_{23} = 0.9.$

```
 m = 10^6
 rho12 = .8;  dlt12 = sqrt(1 - rho12^2)
 rho23 = .9;  dlt23 = sqrt(1 - rho23^2)

 x1 = rnorm(m);  s1 = rnorm(m)
 x2 = rho12*x1 + dlt12*s1
 mean(x1); sd(x1); mean(x2); sd(x2)
 ## 0.0001394826  
 ## 0.9995465
 ## -0.0008933496
 ## 1.000777
 cor(x1, x2)
 ## 0.8001522

 s2 = rnorm(m)
 x3 = rho23*x2 + dlt23*s2
 mean(x3); sd(x3)
 ## -0.001117523
 ## 1.000685
 cor(x2, x3)
 ## 0.9001839

 ## cor(x1, x3)
 ## 0.7200575
 MAT = cbind(x1,x2,x3)
 pairs(MAT[1:30000,], pch=".")
```

[image]

```
 cor(MAT)
 ##           x1        x2        x3
 ## x1 1.0000000 0.8001522 0.7200575
 ## x2 0.8001522 1.0000000 0.9001839
 ## x3 0.7200575 0.9001839 1.0000000
```

Note: For multivariate normal distributions and the given correlations assumed above, I do not claim that $\rho_{13} = 0.72$ is the *only* possible answer. (There are many alternative ways to simulatie normals with specified correlations. The method I used
above is [discussed here](http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/)).

The requirement in the normal case is for the
variance-covariance matrix $\mathbf{V}$ to be positive definite.
The variance-covariance matrix obtained for this particular method of simulation is indeed positive definite; its eigenvalues are all
positive:

```
 V = matrix(c(1.0,  0.8, 0.72,
              0.8,  1.0, 0.9,
              0.72, 0.9, 1.0), byrow=T, nrow=3)
 eigen(V)$values
 ## 2.6155944 0.2960829 0.0883227
```

Baaed on a grid search, it seems values of $\rho_{13}$ in $(0.459, 0.981)$ lead to positive-definite $\mathbf{V}$. (There is a function in R to generate
multivariate normal distributions with specified parameters.)

Here is another example using the simulation method above. With the single change `rho12 = .5`, the program above gives output ending as
follows:

```
 .....
 cor(x1, x3)
 ## 0.4500347
 MAT = cbind(x1,x2,x3)
 pairs(MAT[1:30000,], pch=".")
```

[image]

```
 cor(MAT)
 ##           x1        x2        x3
 ## x1 1.0000000 0.4990733 0.4500347
 ## x2 0.4990733 1.0000000 0.9002335
 ## x3 0.4500347 0.9002335 1.0000000
```

Comment: "Without loss of generality, we use normal distributions" Next you are going to say that without loss of generality, zero correlation implies independence.

Comment: @A.S. Not really. Sloppy wording, which I am changing. Moreover, results from this particular method of generating normal distributions with specified correlations are not the whole story. Adding a note on that.

Comment: My point is that dependence structure between jointly normal variables is LINEAR in nature (something that correlation measures) and is very unrepresentative of non-linear dependencies. To look at your scatter plots is to be mislead about the nature of dependencies between correlated variables (that it "has to" be linear).

Comment: @A.S. Not claiming a definitive, comprehensive answer. I do suppose that during the job interview in question an answer about positive definite variance-covariance matrices in the normal case might have scored some points. If you have a more comprehensive answer, I'd enjoy reading it.

Comment: I was referring specifically to WLOG part. It's increadibly dangerous to generalize at all from the normal case and unfortunately this point is not nearly enough emphasized. Considering it a model example - especially if doing analytical analysis - is ok - but since it's MUCH more interesting/educating to consider non-linear dependencies if you are doing numerical simulations since non-linearity comes for free.

Comment: @A.S. I really do understand that you believe there is a better way to explore this. Never claiming perfection for my answers, I'm eagerly waiting to see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** Playing around with small, non-normal datasets, I found
the following example, for whatever it may be worth. It has $Cor(X, Y) \approx .7,\; Cor(Y, Z) \approx .7$ and $Cor(X, Z) = 0.$

```
 x = -5:5;  z = x^2;  y = (3*x + z)/2
 DTA = cbind(x,y,z)
 t(DTA)
 ##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
 ## x   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3     4     5
 ## y    5    2    0   -1   -1    0    2    5    9    14    20
 ## z   25   16    9    4    1    0    1    4    9    16    25
 cor(DTA)
 ##          x         y         z
 ## x 1.000000 0.7319251 0.0000000
 ## y 0.731925 1.0000000 0.6813851
 ## z 0.000000 0.6813851 1.0000000
 pairs(DTA, pch=19)
```

[image]